# Storybook: Failed to execute 'createElement' on svg files using @svgr/webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, webpack, storybook

My error in the first place is exactly the same as the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54292667/react-storybook-svg-failed-to-execute-createelement-on-document). I'm using the [@svgr/webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svgr/webpack) package to import my `.svg` files as a React component like that:

```js
import Shop from './icons/shop.svg'

return <Shop />
```

It works fine on my app but when I tried to do the same in [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) I get this error:

> Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('static/media/shop.61b51e05.svg') is not a valid name.

So I added the loader into my `.storybook/main.js` file to extends the default Storybook webpack config:

```js
// ...
webpackFinal: async config => {    
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      enforce: 'pre',
      loader: require.resolve('@svgr/webpack'),
    });
```

The error still occurred so I tried to override the default Storybook test for `.svg` files as suggested in the [answer of the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54292998/8583669):

```js
const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find(rule => { rule.test !== undefined ? rule.test.test('.svg') : '' });
fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.svg$/;
```

But then I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'exclude' of undefined

So I decided to make a `console.log` of the `rule.test` and strangely the only default tests coming from Storybook config are theses:

```js
{
  test: /\.md$/,
  ...
}
{
  test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
  ...
}
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  ...
}
{
  test: /\.(stories|story).mdx$/,
  ...
}
{
  test: /\.mdx$/,
  ...
}
{
  test: /\.(stories|story)\.[tj]sx?$/,
  ...
}
{
  test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
  ...
}
```

As you can see there is no test that affects a `.svg` file. So does someone have an idea why my configuration is not working using:

```js
{
  test: /\.svg$/, 
  enforce: 'pre',
  loader: require.resolve('@svgr/webpack'),
}
```

My storybook version is `6.0.0-beta.3`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Your `find` callback always returns `undefined`. Change it to return correct bool:

```
const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find(rule => rule.test && rule.test.test('.svg'));
```

Anyway storybook default config should have a rule for images with this test:
`/\.(svg|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|ttf|woff|woff2|cur|ani|pdf)(\?.*)?$/`.
So your code (but with correct find callback) works fine for me.

Final `main.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.[tj]s'],
    webpackFinal: config => { 
        // Default rule for images /\.(svg|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|ttf|woff|woff2|cur|ani|pdf)(\?.*)?$/
        const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find(rule => rule.test && rule.test.test('.svg'));
        fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.svg$/;  

        config.module.rules.push({
          test: /\.svg$/,
          enforce: 'pre',
          loader: require.resolve('@svgr/webpack'),
        });

        return config;
    } 
};
```

Comment: I said in my question that if I make a `console.log` of my rules there is no `/\.(svg|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|ttf|woff|woff2|cur|ani|pdf)(\?.*)?$/`. `fileLoaderRule` still `undefined` in my case.

Comment: according to your error message some webpack configuration has file-loader configured ... so whats your storybook version?

Comment: Sorry for the laaaate answer. I updated my question.

Comment: This finally allowed me to stop storybook from using url-loader for svgs! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, after fiddling around for long, this finally works. Your answer should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: This worked when I changed it to unshift: `config.module.rules.unshift({ ... })

Comment: I got it working via this, however, I first had to downgrade svgr to v5.4.0, so it would require webpack v4 - I think in my case this was also an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using `webpack@4`, and therefore `@svgr/webpack@5`, I had to use `url-loader`.

```js
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.@(ts|tsx|js|jsx)'],
  webpackFinal: config => { 
    // remove svg from existing rule
    const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find(
      (rule) => rule.test && rule.test.test('.svg')
    )
    fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.svg$/

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack', 'url-loader'],
    })

    return config
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all methods written here, but always got an error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'exclude' of undefined

Finally, i consoled `config.module.rules` and saw its structure: the needed rule is `config.module.rules[5].oneOf[2]`. So i've just hardcoded it with: `config.module.rules[5].oneOf[2] = ['@svgr/webpack']`.

I think that it's a temporary dirty solution, but it works. Hope somebody will point out how to make it more clean and bulletproof.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
webpackFinal: async (config: Configuration) => {
        config.module = config.module || {};
        config.module.rules = config.module.rules || [];
    
        const imageRule = config.module.rules.find((rule) => rule?.['test']?.test('.svg'));
        if (imageRule) {
          imageRule['exclude'] = /\.svg$/;
        }
    
        config.module.rules.push({
          test: /\.svg$/,
          use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
        });
        return config
})



}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Just import it like this:

```
import { ReactComponent as Shop } from './icons/shop.svg'
```

It's transforming it as a React Component so that you can pass properties to it:

```
<Shop fill="tomato" {...args} />
```